# How to get data out of xml XDocument in C#?

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file that I get via a web service. File looks like this:

```
<Z_STU_CRS_TRNS_DOC xmlns="http://testurl">
    <Z_STATUS_CODE>0</Z_STATUS_CODE>
    <Z_STATUS_MSG>Success</Z_STATUS_MSG>
    <Z_STUDENT_ID_SUB_DOC xmlns="http://testurl">
        <Z_STU_ID>000999999</Z_STU_ID>
    </Z_STUDENT_ID_SUB_DOC>
    <Z_CRSE_SUB_DOC xmlns="http://testurl">
        <Z_COURSE xmlns="http://testurl">
            <Z_CRSE_DATA>9999|199901|TEST|9999|1|S|Scuba Diving| |XX</Z_CRSE_DATA>
        </Z_COURSE>
        <Z_COURSE xmlns="testurl">
            <Z_CRSE_DATA>9999|200001|TEST|999|3|A|English 101| |XX</Z_CRSE_DATA>
        </Z_COURSE>
    </Z_CRSE_SUB_DOC>
</Z_STU_CRS_TRNS_DOC>
```

I'm able to consume the service and check for errors but I'm having a tough time actually getting the data out of the XDocument xml file.

```
protected void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, 
                                                 DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    { 
        if (e.Error != null)
            {
                errorLabel.Text = 
                  "The transaction failed. If you feel that you have reached " + 
                  "this in error, please contact the help desk at xxx-xxx-xxxx.";
                errorLabel.Visible = true;
                return;
            }

        XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
        XNamespace ns = "http://testurl";


        //Look for error code from WS
        var field = xml.Descendants(ns + "Z_STATUS_CODE").FirstOrDefault();
        if (field != null)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32((string)field.Value) == 1)
            {
                errorLabel.Text = 
                   "The transaction failed, due to an invalid student id. If you " + 
                   "feel that you have reached this in error, please contact " + 
                   "the help desk at xxx-xxx-xxxx.";
                errorLabel.Visible = true;
                return;
            }
        }
```

I tried many different ways but nothing seems to help. Can someone help?

Comment: What is the error message? In which line does it fail?

Comment: I assume there is no error, but field is always null when it shouldn't be.  1) if you remove the parameter from Descendants such as var field = xml.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(); is field what you would expect?  2) if it is, I'm sure it is a formatting problem with (ns + "Z_STATUS_CODE").  Look at the decendants through the code to see how the namespace and element name should be formatted.  Does that make sense?

Comment: There is no error in this code... I just can't figure out how to get the data out. I'm only able to get the status code. What steps would I take to get the Z_CRSE_DATA out of this doc?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! Posting in case someone else has similar issue.

```
    List<studentRecord> studentCourses = new List<studentRecord>();
    XmlReader reader = xml.CreateReader();
    // Get elements
    while (reader.Read()) 
    {
        if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader.Name == "Z_CRSE_DATA"))
        {
            reader.Read();
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
            {
                studentRecord stuRec = new studentRecord();
                stuRec.rawData = reader.Value;
                studentCourses.Add(stuRec);
            }
        }
    }
    reader.Close();
```

Comment: So, you based it on my reply? If the XMLElement would have an attribute in the future, this will fail, as the next element after XmlNodeType.Element, is the attributes, and then the contents (which was why my example had the double while loop)

Answer (score -1):

You could read the node list, and read the values of the nodes according to their name.

It takes a bit more work, as you have to work through all the nodes itself, but like this you could do it

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string xmldata = @"<Z_STU_CRS_TRNS_DOC xmlns=""http://testurl"">
<Z_STATUS_CODE>0</Z_STATUS_CODE>
<Z_STATUS_MSG>Success</Z_STATUS_MSG>
<Z_STUDENT_ID_SUB_DOC xmlns=""http://testurl"">
    <Z_STU_ID>000999999</Z_STU_ID>
</Z_STUDENT_ID_SUB_DOC>
<Z_CRSE_SUB_DOC xmlns=""http://testurl"">
    <Z_COURSE xmlns=""http://testurl"">
        <Z_CRSE_DATA>9999|199901|TEST|9999|1|S|Scuba Diving| |XX</Z_CRSE_DATA>
    </Z_COURSE>
    <Z_COURSE xmlns=""testurl"">
        <Z_CRSE_DATA>9999|200001|TEST|999|3|A|English 101| |XX</Z_CRSE_DATA>
    </Z_COURSE>
</Z_CRSE_SUB_DOC>
</Z_STU_CRS_TRNS_DOC>";
        string errorTag = "Z_STATUS_CODE",
            statusTag = "Z_STATUS_MSG";

        XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(xmldata);
        XNamespace ns = "http://testurl";
        int errorCode = -1;
        string statusMessage = string.Empty;

        using (XmlReader reader = xml.CreateReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                if (!string.Equals(reader.Name, errorTag) &&
                    !string.Equals(reader.Name, statusTag))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                string currentName = reader.Name;
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    if (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Text)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (string.Equals(currentName, errorTag))
                    {
                        errorCode = int.Parse(reader.Value);
                    }
                    if (string.Equals(currentName, statusTag))
                    {
                        statusMessage = reader.Value;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (errorCode == -1)
        {
            // no tag found
            Console.WriteLine("No tag found named: {0}", errorTag);
        }
        else if (errorCode == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Operation was a success!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Operation failed with error code {0}", errorCode);
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(statusMessage))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Status message: {0}", statusMessage);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```